# Is there a way to hide my subreddit behind a survey they have to fill out to gain access?

Tags: controls, hidden, reddit

I have a military subreddit that I need to hide behind a secure wall to control who does and does not have access to it. The current hidden policy just shows a contact form for contacting the mods to gain access but I need something that asks specific questions in order for the users to gain access. I would rather ask the questions up front than having the mods have to reply to a message to ask those same questions.

Comment: This is not a greatly worded question. Short answer is yes, in basically any backend web language (or using JS), but your question does not provide an avenue to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was hard for me to word this. If you look at https://www.reddit.com/r/TheHomeFrontFamily/ You can see how my subreddit is hidden. How do I change that form into a survey where I ask multiple questions instead of just the contact form?

Comment: I don't actually see a form on my mobile device, it is just a protected thread. In terms of what you want, it sounds like you want the ability to programmatically allow users into your subreddit. This is possible using the Reddit API as noted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/279qlu/adding_a_user_as_an_approved_submitter_with_praw/ in terms of providing the survey after directly going to the subreddit link, I'm not sure it's possible, but you could easily develop a landing page yourself that uses the API and redirects to the correct place on survey submission.

Comment: Hm. I looked at that and the link that comment leads you to "redirects too many times" for chrome and won't load. If it isn't possible that is okay, I will just have to rethink my strategy. :)